# Chamando função em JavaScript no momento errado

Tags: javascript, funções, zoom

Boa noite, estou tentando criar uma pagina que exibe uma imagem em uma modalBox com a função de zoom, porém estou enfrentando o problema de que mesmo clicando fora da miniatura da imagem, a função de zoom está sendo executada, alguem saberia como resolver? O código está abaixo:

```
<span class='zoom' id='ex3'>
   <img id="myImg" src="http://t.wallpaperweb.org/wallpaper/nature/1920x1200/Trolltunga_Odda_Norway.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">
   <p>Hover</p>
</span>


<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <div class="zoom">
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01" width=300 height=300>
  </div>


  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

```
$(function(){
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    $('.zoom').zoom({
      on: 'click',
      url: this.src
    });
  }
  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
 }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens as classes do bootstrap na ordem errada; `modal-content` é o que engloba o conteúdo da modal, ao passo que `zoom` é o que é englobado pelo modal-content e engloba a imagem.

Tens também uma class na `img` que lhe dá o poder da modal-content, o que nao é certo.

troca o html da modal content para

```
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="zoom">
      <img id="img01" class="pre-zoom">
    </div>
  </div>
```

e adiciona o CSS:

```
.pre-zoom {
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
}
```